# OBIEE11g date manipulation/comparison via the advanced SQL filter

Tags: date, datetime, obiee

I'm running into an issue in Analysis with the Advanced SQL Filter and date comparisons.

I have two date fields, `Report Date` and `Validated Date`. I'm doing a comparison in the Advanced SQL Filter where these two dates should match.

In this case, the `Report Date` is `28-FEB-2012 12:00` and the `Validated Date` is `28-FEB-2012 20:00`.  My analysis says these two dates are equal.  Except technically, they are not.

Expressed in SQL, I'm trying to accomplish this:

```
TO_CHAR(REPORT_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY') = TO_CHAR(VALIDATED_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

I've tried that line in the advanced SQL filter and it's not working. I've tried:

```
EVALUATE(to_date(%1, %2), REPORT_NAME, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

...and OBIEE is not accepting it.

So, OBIEE 11g gurus, how do I properly compare these dates so it's clear that they do not match?

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at the physical SQL generated by OBIEE? Maybe there are differences in milliseconds. Do you need to compare hours and minutes or would a comparison with CAST AS DATE function would work. 
Also, you don't mention why Evaluate doesn't work, have you adjusted the parameter in OBIEE configuration files to use the function?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could convert both to timestamps and compare them with [timestampdiff()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/bi.1111/e10540/sqlref.htm#CHDDBJDJ)

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(interval, timestamp1, timestamp2)
```

example:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF
( 
  SQL_TSI__SECOND, 
  CAST (report_date as TIMESTAMP),
  CAST ( validated_date as TIMESTAMP)
)
FROM table;
```

Then you could use the result as a condition (e.g. if difference is greater than 0 seconds then X)

The most detailed interval is SQL_TSI_SECOND so this would not work if there is a difference in milliseconds as @Ana GH suggested